# validar numero de telefono sin que el campo sea obligatorio

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer un formulario de contacto y he copiado un código que en contre por ahi :) (creo que no hace falta decir que soy novato en javascript) bueno lo que intento hacer es que el campo del numero de teléfono no sea obligatorio pero si se introducen  un numero poder validarlo.

Mi expresion regular para validar  el numero de telefono es la siguiente:

```
// Phone Validation
$.fn.conformyPhoneValidate     = function () {
    //var phoneRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;     
    var phoneRegexp = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3,5}$/im;                      
        return phoneRegexp.test($(this).val());
}
```

Despues de validar el telefono tengo esto:

```
/ Formulario de contacto Enviar
$("#contactForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    ///var $this = $(this);

    //  Contact Form Input Value 
    // Valor de entrada del formulario de contacto
    let $this         = $(this);
    
    let phone         = $("#contactPhone").val().trim();        
    
    let validatePhone = $("#contactPhone").conformyPhoneValidate();
    
    

    if (name =='' || email =='' || message == ''  || textInput == '' ) {
        $(this).parent().find("span").addClass("error");
        if($('.empty-form').css("display") == "none"){
            $('.empty-form').stop().slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else if (!validatePhone === true ) {
        $("#contactPhone").parent().find("span").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
        if($('.phone-invalid').css("display") == "none"){
            $('.phone-invalid').stop().slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $this.find(':submit').append('<span class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse ml-3"></span>');
        $this.find(':submit').attr('disabled','true');
        $.ajax({
            url: "bat/send_mail.php?mail=request",
            data: {
                contact_name: name,
                contact_email: email,
                contact_phone: phone,                    
                contact_message: message
            },
```

espero alguien pueda echarme una mano u orientarme o en su defecto hacerlo de manera diferente :D

Comment: En la validación puedes devolver true si el campo está vacío

Comment: dices en la validacion  regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como

```
// Phone Validation
$.fn.conformyPhoneValidate     = function () {
    const phoneRegexp = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3,5}$/im;
    const value = $(this).val().trim();

    return !value || phoneRegexp.test(value);
}
```

Es decir, devuelves true si el campo está vacío o si el valor cumple la regex.

Comment: si funciona!!  muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda